# How to add value in session in array form & fetch the session value in ci?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

There is a link in my view as shown below.

```
<a href="<php echo site_url('page/cart/'.$id)"; ?>Cart</a>
```

Here, $id is product's id.

Controller:
function cart($id)

```
{
$this->session->set_userdata('ids[]', $id);
$data['title']='My Website | Cart';
$data['content']=$this->load->view('page/cart', $data, TRUE);
$this->load->view('template', $data);
}
```

View: cart.php

```
<?php
echo $this->session->userdata('ids[]');
?>
<?php if($cart_ids!=''): ?>
<div class="cart-info">

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<td class="image">Product Image</td>
<td class="name">Product Name</td>
<td class="id">Product Id</td>
<td class="quantity">Quantity</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($cart_ids as $cart_id): ?>
<tr>
<td class="image">Product Image</td>
<td class="name">Product Name</td>
<td class="id">Product Id</td>
<td class="quantity">Quantity</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

First when I click cart, there should be set a session of id in array form and when I click for the 2nd time, the value of id should be added to the session without replacing the previous one. And secondly, I want to fetch the value of the id from the session in foreach condition.

Answer (score 0):

We have to inject the new session with the current session
So basically:

```
 $new_session = $this->uri->segment(3); // fetches the id from ('page/cart/'.$id)
 $sessions = $this->session->userdata('sessionList');
 $sessions[] = $new_session // Or use $this->uri->segment(3) directly
 $this->session->set_userdata('ses_list', $ses_list);
```

[Session Doc](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: its not secure way to directly added the id into session from url